# TypeScript: type with list of properties based on the same pattern

Tags: typescript

I want to have a `type` that can include any number of properties based on a predefined pattern like this:

```js
type Values = {
  id: number;
  id1?: number;
  id2?: number;
  id2?: number;
  id3?: number;
  id4?: number;
  id5?: number;
  // ...
  somethingElse: string;
  anotherOne: number;
};
```

But because I don't exactly know how many ids there are, I thought that there is may something like this:

```js
// pseudo-code
type Values = {
  id: number;
  [`id${index}`?: number];
  somethingElse: string;
  anotherOne: number;
};
```

So I don't have to use `[k: string]: number`.

If there is not such a way, what would be the easiest/best way to achieve something similar without just adding a random (very high) amount of `idX` properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template literal type that has a `number` in it in an index signature. This will allow any property that follows the specified pattern, but no others:

```
type Values = {
  id: number;
  [key: `id${number}`]: number
  somethingElse: string;
  anotherOne: number;
} 

let v:Values = {
  id: 0,
  somethingElse: "",
  anotherOne: 0,
  id0: 1,
  id22:1,
}

let v2:Values = {
  id: 0,
  somethingElse: "",
  anotherOne: 0,
  id0: 1,
  id22:1,
  bad: 0,
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDD0oAgBwZwUwK4BMD2BaAxipdgBcBPKOCANQEMAbBOGCAXggG9gIIBLJALggDsEAtgCM4AJwDcrCAG0A1nAI8ABpwAkTfsLEBfJQF0emkaKkwUAuHgAW7XgHMAopXg8YeUbbuS25XimtiAPK8cIaCxpLaECCUlhAAblwU1LQMzFKcPAAMADSm5pY29k4uEABEZXk+fgGiwaEQuRlIWTwAjFUcSABM3VwdwNoxcfF9yTR0jCxsmY2dZhbWniUNFZ2+-lZBIdmdnK0QAzM9fUcQQuTcc4MgQA)

This is available in TS 4.4 and up ([PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512))

Comment: thanks a lot. was hoping for something like this ... seems like I didn't look enough ;)

Comment: How can I iterate over all properties and only grab the `id${number}` ones? With `Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => { if (/id\d+/s.test(key) && typeof values[key] === 'number') { ids.push(values[key]); } });` TS is complaining about `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Values'.`

Comment: @PhilippKyeck You will need to  use type assertions there. Typescript won't type check that part.

Comment: @PhilippKyeck or better yet. A custom type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDD0oAgBwZwUwK4BMD2BaAxipdgBcBPKOCANQEMAbBOGCAXggG9gIIBLJALggDsEAtgCM4AJwDcrCAG0A1nAI8ABpwAkTfsLEBfJQF0emkaKkwUAuHgAW7XgHMAopXg8YeUbbuS25XimtiAPK8cIaCxpLaECCUlhAAblQ0MFwU1LQMzFKcPAAMADSm5pY29k4uEABElYU+fgGiwaEQBdlIuTwAjLUcSABMfVzdwNogAGYIvBh47Ci8HDAAkkgA0goAFPKKEG4e9gCUPFsLECpI6kY6SllsopYIovOgnAA6SADUoDAAdHi0eJsFPsRjE4pwUnxwmJpHpGDDgIEhAArODTb5bGDrRLpGD7b5jFCiBzkDBWdaAgj7BgAPmYHDGEHW7CWqw2WypADIORBCMQUAzsck5Ao9Ax6IwAOSXUQSqlMXo-KAIGBkwW0YUEPT7cQQKLabVAA